# cakephp how to handle admin login redirect

Tags: cakephp

I have created a little project with an admin section.
I am using admin routes to redirect to admin actions in my controllers.
The website has pages that are available to everyone with no login required.
To access the /admin or /admin/users, etc... You must login.

I have spread my admin actions across my controllers like "admin_login", "admin_users", ...

So my question is, when someone goes to /admin/users or some other adminpage, I have to check in each controller action if the user is in the session and otherwise redirect to thelogin form.

Is there a way to do this in one place? I used a beforefilter in my AppController class, but because my controllers contain a combination of "standard" actions and "admin" actions, putting it in the AppController doesn't work for this case because it always redirects when nog logged in.

In my AppController I have this code

```
public function beforeFilter(){
   if(!$this->Session->check('User')){
      $this->redirect('/admin/users/login');
   }
}
```

When using something like this, I get an infinite loop:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
   if(!empty($this->request->params['admin'])){
       if(!$this->Session->check('User')){
          $this->redirect('/admin/users/login');
       }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are missing is some mapping of what which roles can access. One simple "one-file" solution is [tiny](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/). You could also say then that all admin_ prefixed actions are available for the admin role for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this tutorial because I'm not using Auth but my own script.
A little outdated but with some adjustments it fitted my needs.

```
function beforeFilter() {
        // if admin url requested
        if(isset($this->request->params['admin']) && $this->request->params['admin']) {
            // check user is logged in
            if( !$this->Session->check('User') ) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('You must be logged in for that action.');
                $this->redirect('/login');
            }

            // save user data
            $this->_User = $this->Session->read('User');
            $this->set('user',$this->_User);

            // change layout
            $this->layout = 'admin';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [admin routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing) ?

You should have a `UsersController` with `login` and `signup` methods for example, that will be accessbile to everybody, and `admin_edit`, for examlpe, that will need login.

Method `admin_edit` corresponds to the url `/admin/users/edit`

In `AppController`, you should include the Auth Component.
Example

```
public $components = array('Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'admin' => false,
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'),
        'authenticate' => array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email')))));
```

And in `UsersController`, you should have something like

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('login', 'register');
}
```

Comment: Yes I do, i have updated it in my question.  I allready have the methods you suggest. The question is how to detect if someone can perform the admin action. I don't want to check if a user is logged in in every action, but putting it in the appcontroller beforefilter redirects always when not logged in, and I also don't want that.

Comment: I updated the answer. Let me know if including Auth and adding the allowed methods works